# pygtk package for archlinux arm

Tags: raspberry-pi4, archlinux-arm

Is the pygtk package available somewhere for archlinux arm?

I'm trying to run chirp (https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Running_Under_Linux)
on a raspberry pi 4 running archlinux. Seems most people are running rasbian and sounds like pygtk is available on raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

The pygtk package from aur was able to compile on the pi:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pygtk/

I had to modify the PKGBUILD to allow building on arm, check comments in AUR. Hopefully the PKGBUILD will be updated to support arm here in the near future.